# nBomber runs hundreds of times even if we specify copies:1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nbomber

I just came across this very nice load testing tool for .NET and I wrote my first code:

```
var connectStep = Step.Create("ConnectReceive", async context =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Step was executed.");

    return Response.Ok();
});

var scenario = ScenarioBuilder.CreateScenario("LotsOfConnections", connectStep)
    .WithLoadSimulations(Simulation.KeepConstant(copies: 1, during: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));

NBomberRunner.RegisterScenarios(scenario).Run();
```

However when I run this I see `Step was executed` hundreds of times in my console screen.
I specified `copies: 1, during: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)` so based on my understanding it should only run once within a period of 10 seconds.
why is it running numerous times

Comment: According to the comments in this [Load Simulations Intro](https://nbomber.com/docs/general-concepts/#load-simulations-intro) sample, *"`KeepConstant` runs a fixed number of scenario copies (threads) and executes as many iterations as possible for a specified amount of time."*

Comment: @RufusL yes just found out. How do I limit the iterations though?

Comment: I don't know, I've never heard about it until I saw this question. My first assumption is to not add a load simulation if you don't want to simulate a load. But your question is stated as: *"why is it running numerous times?"*. Perhaps that should be modified?

Comment: This tool is amazing. so simple to use and yet lacks a very small but rather very crucial setting. Tried to use a lot of other load testing tools and this one amazed me how easy is to work with. Hope the owner adds this option.

Comment: From reading the samples on their page, it's clear that you can add multiple steps to a scenario. Why not just add one that sleeps for 10 seconds? It's not exactly clear what you want to do (would be helpful if you clarified your question), but I don't see why that wouldn't work. Have you tried something like that? I added an answer with a sample below.

Comment: Trying to load a web server to check how many connections can handle..

Answer (score 0):

> *why is it running numerous times*

According to this [Load Simulations Intro](https://nbomber.com/docs/general-concepts/#load-simulations-intro) sample, *"`KeepConstant` runs a fixed number of scenario copies (threads) and executes as many iterations as possible for a specified amount of time."*

---

It's not exactly clear what the scenario is that you want.

- Do you want it to just run once, but take 10 seconds? If so, you could add a step to the scenario that sleeps for 10 seconds after the connect step, and remove the `.WithLoadSimulations` from the scenario.
- Do you want the scenario to run many times, but only once every 10 seconds? If so, you could add a step to the scenario that sleeps for 10 seconds after the connect step, and then add a longer duration to the load simulation:

For example:

```
var connectStep = Step.Create("ConnectReceive", async context =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Step was executed.");    
    return Response.Ok();
});

var sleepStep = Step.Create("Sleep", async context =>
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    return Response.Ok();
});

// Connect to our system once every 10 seconds for a minute
var scenario = ScenarioBuilder
    .CreateScenario("ManyConnections", connectStep, sleepStep);
    .WithLoadSimulations(Simulation.KeepConstant(copies: 1, 
        during: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)));
```